# Python pandas--how to merge 2 csv if the relevant column data is "close enough?"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I want to merge two csvs using pandas. The column of interest is relative time and I am interested in merging if the two times are "close enough"--i.e. the times do not have to be exactly the same, just near each other. I think I have successfully merged the csv and created an output csv but it is blank and I am getting `Key Error: 'name of column I am merging'` so I think this is because none of the values are exactly the same.

```
raw = pd.read_csv('Specimen_RawData_2.csv', low_memory = False)
optical = pd.read_csv('results_avg_optical_strain3.csv', low_memory = False)

result = pd.merge(raw, optical[['Exx, mean']], on = 'Relative Time (s)')
result.to_csv('Results.csv')
```

I am not really interested in rounding the time values, because the exact value is of interest. I just want to merge the data where the two values are nearest each other. Ex:

raw:

```
22  1.097   0.11339 1.47275         0.053

23  1.101   0.12211 1.59291         0.057

24  1.105   0.13051 1.71423         0.061
```

optical:

```
1   1   1   4.54E-05    cam0_006807_418.910.csv 418.91  0.058

2   2   2   4.48E-05    cam0_006808_418.975.csv 418.975 0.123

3   3   3   0.000138274 cam0_006809_419.037.csv 419.037 0.185
```

I would merge these where the time value is `0.057` in raw and `0.058` in optical. 
Any help is appreciated. I will edit this if there are any questions as I know this is confusing to read through!

Comment: Let's look at [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas-merge-asof) there is a `tolerance` parameter and `direction` parameter that can be used.

Comment: *just near each other* needs a precise definition

Comment: 'near each other' I realize is vague and not precisely defined but that was somewhat on purpose--I don't necessarily need/want any specific criteria, I just want to merge the two values that are closest to each other. does that change anything?

Comment: and pd.merge_asof seems very helpful--I hadn't found that before. I am still getting the KeyError, however, so maybe something in my original code was wrong.